# Backdrop-filter not working in desktop safari

Tags: html, css, webkit

I am trying to add backdrop blur effect using css, jquery is used to make `.imageoverlay` slide up and down on hover. The backdrop blur effect works fine on chrome while it only works sometimes on safari but the majority of times it does not.

```
.imgoverlay {
  position                  : absolute;
  top                       : 100%;
  left                      : 50%;
  transform                 : translate(-50%, -100%);
  width                     : 100%;
  height                    : 150px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5vw;
  border-bottom-left-radius : 0.5vw;
  background                : linear-gradient(rgba(98, 98, 98, 0.4), rgba(98, 98, 98, 0.3));
  filter                    : drop-shadow(0px -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  backdrop-filter           : saturate(180%) blur(3px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter   : saturate(180%) blur(3px);
  display                   : none;
} 

function dots(){
  $(".dots").off("mouseover mouseleave").on("mouseover mouseleave",function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".imgoverlay").slideToggle(300, "swing")
  })
}
```

Comment: Don't know an answer to your Q but this helped me get 'backdrop-filter' working with desktop Safari. While it knows the CSS feature without prefix, `@supports` doesn't. 14.0.2